# Floating UL right causes last LI to drop/break onto new line - WHY?

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I'm trying to create a horizontal navigation that floats to the right. Once it floats to the right and I then float all list items to the left. The last list item breaks onto a new line.

The problems disappears when I remove any margin properties. But margin is very important to me because I've displayed the anchor tags to block in order to make the whole area clickable. I've done this for touch screen purposes.

Can anyone help me to make all the words in my ul display on one line as it all floats to the right while still using margin and padding?

https://jsfiddle.net/samuelcrockford/4a8oovjs/1/#&togetherjs=P0dq57flOy

Please see example using the js fiddle link above

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


nav {
  float:right;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav ul {
  float:right;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

nav ul li:first-child { margin-left: 0;}


nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set all elements' `box-sizing` property to `border-box`:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will include both border widths and padding sizes in the complete width of an element- fixing the problem in terms of padding.

Use `px` values for the margins, to fix that issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've wasted so much of my time trying to solve this issue. You are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

**Add 100% width to the ul tag**

```
    nav ul {
      width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used px in the end instead of % and now all works fine. See answer below and again thank you for your time.